# How do I setup a website on Ubuntu Server 12.04 with PHP, MySQL, and webmail?

Tags: ubuntu, php, mysql, mail-server

I have a computer in my room running Ubuntu Server 12.04 and I would like to know how to run a website off of it.

I already have installed PHP and MySQL but I don't know how to install webmail or how to get my domain name to direct to the IP of my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what kind of IP address you have (assuming static IPv4 here) and with whom your domain is hosted.

You will need to set the *A Resource Record* of your domain to point to your IP address. The provider I use for hosting domains lets me change the DNS entries online, but you might have to open a support ticket with your provider if he needs to change it for you.

UPDATE: Your provider seems to offer a tool for editing DNS online as well, take a look at their [documentation](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/680/managing-dns-for-your-domain-names). At the end of the page you will find links to detailed documentation on the different DNS records, you need the one called "Adding or Editing **A Records**".

As for the mail server, I suggest you start with postfix and dovecot, which can be installed together on ubuntu with the package *dovecot-postfix*. If you manage to set it up to your liking, you will then have to change the **MX Record** of your domain to point to your IP address as well, so you can receive e-mail from the outside world.

Comment: I have a static IPv4 address, and the domain is hosted with godaddy. Do I need to do anything with name servers? And I only want backend mail, something that my mail client can connect to, how would I install a mailserver?